# Android: How to recreate (or refresh) the gridview in a fragment

Tags: android, gridview, android-fragments, android-arrayadapter

I am building a gallery like application. It consists of a grid view showing the thumbnail of the photos and a button to take a new picture. To get the thumbnails of the images on the phone, I used an ArrayAdapter in the fragment and set it up with to the gridview.

The problem is that when I took photo and scan it to the Android content resolver, it doesn't show up in the gridview instantaneously. I have to rotate the screen or exit the app and reopen the app, so that the fragment is recreated and the thumbnail of the new photo shows up in the gallery.

Is there anyway that I can force the fragment to restart, or force the adapter to setup again?

I try to call the mAdapter.setAdapter in the activity of this fragment, but there is not allowed with the following error:

```
android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once the underlying dataset of the adapter has changed, you need to call `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` to update the GridView.

Comment: Then do I have to keep an instance of my adapter. I am setting up the adapter in this way: mGridView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(mItems));. If I need to call notifyDataSetChanged(), do I have to change the code to ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(mItems); mGridView.setAdapter(adapter); so that I can call the function adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()?

Comment: Okay, it works. Basically what I did is 1) keep an instance of ArrayAdapter 2) rescan the images to mItems, 3) then call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged().